# Temperature and friction relationship

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, temperature, friction

I was actually conducting an experiment investigating the influence of temperature on the coefficient of friction.

I am having trouble understanding the scientific reasoning behind the way it can reduce or increase friction.

Can someone explain exactly why the increase in temperature, increases AND decreases the frictional force acting on different materials? Based on either the modern view or the old view

Comment: tempature increases AND decreases the frictional force? are you sure

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct, temperature cannot make frictional force increase or decrease

Possible explanation:

If the temperature increases then distance between the particles of the body increases due to thermal expansion which results in smoothening the surface accordingly and the frictional force between them decreases.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that increasing the temperature will only increase the friction on the surface it can also decrease with time which depends upon temperature difference between the heat source and surface or the mechanism which is providing heat to the surface and rising the temperature of the surface.

Let's take an example that how friction can decrease with increase in temperature.

Let's assume a surface made of spikes of rubber, so as we place an object over it and rub at the same time the friction feels more where as if we heat that surface until it gets totally melted, and now we put an object over it and then rub over, the friction feels less because of the thermal expansion of the particles and as the temperature reaches its melting point it starts melting and after which it will be categorised as fluid and then comes the concept of visocity. Which is also called fluid friction and it is much more less strong than the friction on solid surfaces.

And now according to your statement that friction increases on increasing the temperature:-

The reason is quite similar to the first one BUT now we are going to take surface made up of metal which has spikes and also we will take an object which has spikes as well. As we can understand in much easier way by the concept of interlocking between the two surfaces.

So as we increase the temperature every object tends to get expanded with the increase in temperature and same happens with the metal. As the metal expands the spikes will also get expanded and become much bigger than before which will interlock the surface of the object much better than before so as the interlocking between the surfaces increases it will be much harder to slide object over it. And this is how the friction increases over increase in temperature.

But remember that if we increase the temperature too much till the melting point of the metal it will also start melting and will result in the same scenario as the example of the surface made up of rubber.

Hope it will help you understand better!
Thank you!